# King of Tokyo Complete Destruction card question

Tags: king-of-tokyo

I roll 1,2,3,3,3,3 on my first roll and after rerolling I achieve 1,2,3,energy,punch,health do I get the 9 victory points or does re rolling cancel out the bonus 9 points; do I need to roll them on my first roll or just a normal final roll?

Comment: I don't have the rules in front of me so I won't make this an authoritative answer, but I'm pretty sure based on balance alone that it has to be referring to your *final* roll - that card would be totally unplayable (definitely not worth purchasing for 3 energy) if it had to be your first roll, and also completely uninteresting (it would happen 100% by luck; you wouldn't be able to make any interesting decisions of whether to go for the combo or not)

Comment: In the future, please add the text of relevant cards.

Answer (score 2):

You only ever tally/score/use your roll when you're done rolling.  Typically, this is after the third roll.

Thus, Total Destruction only cares about what dice are up at the end of your third roll, so you score the 9 in your scenario.

Comment: Worth adding: Conversely, if the dice show 1,2,3,energy,punch,health after one roll and you reroll the health to get a final roll of 1,2,3,energy,energy,punch, you get no points.